# Web deploy on iis 8.5 installation using chef

Tags: windows, iis, chef-recipe

I'm new to the chef stuff and I need to install web deploy v3.5 on windows server 2012 r2.

I've tried to use next

```
windows_package "Install MSDeploy V3.5" do
  source http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/4/4/D446D154-2232-49A1-9D64-F5A9429913A4/WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi
  installer_type :msi
  action :install
  not_if {::File.exists?("C:\\Program Files\\IIS\\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\\msdeploy.exe")}
end
```

But it didn't work.

The output says 
[2015-06-18T07:24:21-07:00] INFO: Starting installat
ion...this could take awhile.
[2015-06-18T07:24:32-07:00] INFO: Chef Run complete
in 17.906293 seconds

But it seems like nothing was installed. No web deploy service. nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Need quotes around the source file path